# How can I display a textView corresponding to a random image?

Tags: android

I want to display a textView corresponding to the button and the image knowing that the image is random. For example when the red image is displayed and the button `btn1` is clicked, the textView is displayed.

I tried this code but the textView is still invisible.

```
public class colors extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn1, btn2, btn4;
ImageView img;
TextView txt1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_colors);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.red);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blue);
    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green); //st.setEnabled(false); 

    int[] cards = {R.drawable.green, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.blue};
    Random r = new Random();
    final int n = r.nextInt(3);
    img.setImageResource(cards[n]);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (n == 2) {
                txt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You are randomizing n value `final int n=r.nextInt(3)`. Therefore only when n ramdmomly is 2 does the textView becomes visible

Comment: Yes when n =2 then thrR.drawable.red will be displayed ----> the texView will be displayed but on my case the textView still invisible

Comment: from what you show above txt1 will only become visible when you click btn1 and n==2. If you have more code you have to show it

Comment: I edit my post . The txt1 should be visible only when R.drawable.red is diplayed and the btn1 is clicked

Comment: please indent your code please. It is very difficult to understand with everything on one line

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand from your question, you want something along the lines of:

```
public class colors extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn1, btn2, btn3;
    ImageView img;
    TextView txt1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.red);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blue);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.green); //st.setEnabled(false);

        final int[] cards = {R.drawable.green, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.blue};
        Random r = new Random();
        final int n = r.nextInt(3);
        img.setImageResource(cards[n]);
        img.setId(cards[n]);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // green is cards[0], red is cards[1], blue is cards[2]
                if (img.getId() == cards[1]) {
                    txt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    // txt1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Set the ID of the image to be the same as the ID `(R.drawable.red)` from the int array. This way you can check for it later when `bt1` is clicked.